# Selecting which Outlook profile to use

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, user-profiles

I have two Microsoft Outlook 2010 profiles.  I want my primary profile to be loaded by default, no questions asked, when I start Outlook.  I have set this up correctly in *Control Panel, Mail*.

However, when I want to access my secondary profile, I assumed I would have been able to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> when starting Outlook to see the *Choose Profile* dialog.  But this doesn't seem to be the case.

Is there a way to choose another profile when "Always use this profile" is enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about older versions, but Outlook [2003](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/command-line-switches-HP001003110.aspx), [2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-outlook-2007-HP001218589.aspx), [2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/command-line-switches-for-outlook-2010-HP010354956.aspx) and [2013](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/command-line-switches-for-outlook-2013-HA102606406.aspx) all support the following two command-line parameters:

- **/profile profilename** - Loads the specified profile. If your profile name contains a space, enclose the profile name in quotation marks (" ").
- **/profiles** - Opens the **Choose Profile** dialog box regardless of the **Options** setting on the **Tools** menu.

You can create separate shortcuts for each profile by specifying the appropriate parameter in the shortcut's **Target** field.